# Can I get a fixed clock in kotlinx time?

Tags: kotlin, java-time, kotlinx

I'm trying to transition my code to use kotlinx.datetime instead of the java.time library as I'd like to make use of the serialization benefits of the kotlinx library (it can serialize instant using the `@Serialize` annotation).

However, i have tests that are using the java.time.Clock and while there is a kotlinx.datetime.Clock class, it appears much more limited than the java one.

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing as this (which uses `java.time.Clock` and `java.time.Instant`):

```
val clockFixed = Clock.fixed(Instant.now().minusMillis(1000), ZONE_ID_UTC)
```

using the kotlinx library? It doesn't have to be exactly like for like but I would like a clock that always returns the same instant so I can use it for tests and for production code.

Comment: Did you search the documentation? I wouldn’t expect it to be hard to find if it exists.

Comment: Also if its not already included, would it be hard to implement yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kotlinx.datetime.Clock` is a very simple interface that (as of version `0.4.0`) only includes a single function declaration.

```kotlin
/**
 * A source of [Instant] values.
 *
 * See [Clock.System][Clock.System] for the clock instance that queries the operating system.
 */
public interface Clock {
    /**
     * Returns the [Instant] corresponding to the current time, according to this clock.
     */
    public fun now(): Instant

    ...
}
```

As of `0.4.0` there is no implementation of a `Fixed` clock provided by the library itself. However, you can easily provide your own implementation of a `Fixed` clock and make it available on the `companion object` of the `Clock` interface.

```
public class FixedClock(private val fixedInstant: Instant): Clock {
    override fun now(): Instant = fixedInstant
}

private fun Clock.Companion.Fixed(fixedInstant: Instant): Clock = FixedClock(fixedInstant)
```

Then, you can use it like the official `System` clock provided by the library.

```kotlin
val systemClock: Clock = Clock.System
val fixedClock: Clock = Clock.Fixed(...)
```